# Is it possible to use the Hootoo HT-TM05 as a wireless adapter (not a wireless AP or router)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-bridge

I have a Hootoo HT-TM05 that I bought a while back.  I never seem to need it as a wireless router, but I would much rather it be used as a wireless adapter.  As an example.  I have a bunch of raspberry Pi's that I set up, or do testing and development with.  It would be great to be able to use the TM05 as a ready to go cat-5 port I can plug into.  This avoids having to set up the WiFi on a test pi and allows me to be wireless etc.

Now I know there are other devices that can do EXACTLY what I'm describing in my example.  The question I'm asking is specifically about the TM05.  Can I use it like that?  Is is possible with some modding like with dd-wrt etc...

Currently from what I can tell I can use it in a wireless bridge mode but only as a wireless AP way.  Once bridge mode is setup I can connect to the TM05's wireless network and access the internet.  But for some reason the CAT5 jack seems to be disabled.

Comment: Short answer. No.

Comment: Long answer: Yes, by using OpenWrt, but it's not supported by the manufacturer, will void the warranty, and is not reversible (at least, not yet). See [@Tim_Stewart's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1352836/776028) for more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you have accepted the other answer as correct, it infact **is not correct**.

There is third party firmware available for this device. It as far as I could find, has no support through dd-wrt to do what you want.

It does however have firmware support for **openWRT**.  I don't have this device, so I can't claim what kind of compatibility it actually has. Check the forums before you flash it.

Here is the openwrt page for this device:
https://openwrt.org/toh/hootoo/hootoo_ht-tm05

I have had very good experiences with openwrt. At this point I prefer it over dd-wrt. Follow the flash instructions carefully and you should be fine.

Please note: At this point there **is no way** to flash this device back to the manufacturers firmware. This will void the warranty if applicable, and the openWRT firmware will be final.

Hope this helps you out, if it does please accept this answer so people searching know your first answer was not correct.

Comment: 1) Instructions on how to install. - These are located at the bottom of the link in this answer. Follow them exactly and you will have OpenWrt installed in no time.  2) Step #7. How to put the device in firmware update mode. - Using Windows 10 I had SolarWinds TFTP server setup. Just remember to disable the firewall or add an exception rule so the TM05 can connect. Power up TM05, set ip on pc nic, plug cat5 (pc to tm05), turn on TFTP server ensure 10.10.10.254 is binded, power off TM05, hold in reset pinhole, power on device, wait about 10-15 seconds to see activity in TFTP server window.

Comment:  glad you got it going!

Answer (score 0):

The HT-TM05's cat5 port is a WAN, not a LAN. This port is used only for input signal, not an output signal. So you can't connect it with the client device. If HT-TM05 has a LAN port, you can use the client device to connect to the LAN port to achieve what you want. But it did not.
More about this - [How to Configure Hootoo HT-TM05 (AP/ router / bridge)](https://www.ufask.com/configure-ht-tm05-ap-router-bridge-152)

Comment: As much as I hate to hear it, this is the correct answer.  I was just hoping for some sort of dd-wrt release that would change the Hootoo design.  I'm positive that once there is a release as such you will be able to use the cat5 port for both LAN and WAN purposes.

Comment: While practically right (at least for stock firmware), the explanation is still backwards... Ethernet ports **don't** distinguish between "input signal" or "output signal". It's the Wi-Fi module that *does* distinguish, and needs to be switched between "access point" mode and "station/client" mode. (I believe all Wi-Fi hardware is technically capable of station mode, only the configuration panel often omits it.)